# TodoMVC - Ember.run.once

Tags: ember.js, todomvc

I've been working on the [Todo MVC App for Ember](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc). In the model, I noticed a call to a commit() method wrapped in `Ember.run.once` See: https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/js/models/todo.js#L9

```js
todoDidChange: function () {
    Ember.run.once(this, function () {
        this.get('store').commit();
    });
}.observes('isCompleted', 'title');
```

How does wrapping `this.get('store').commit()` in `Ember.run.once` help? I changed the method to just do:

```js
todoDidChange: function () {
    this.get('store').commit();
}.observes('isCompleted', 'title');
```

But I dont see any visible difference. I read [the documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_once) and a [previos SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597869/what-is-ember-runloop-and-how-does-it-work) haven't been able to figure it out.

Is this a case where the difference doesn't show because it's just a small app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer as a [response to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732285/ember-js-managing-asynchronous-events-callbacks/15750336#15750336).

If you have a listener on each item of an array like this:

```js
App.IssuesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ 
    issue_list: ['a','b','c'],
    issueListObserver : function(){
        Ember.run.once(this, this.categorize);
    }.observes('issue_list.@each"),

    this.categorize: function () {
        console.log('foo');
    }
});
```

Without `Ember.run.once`, `this.categorize()` will be called for each item manipulated in the list. If three items are modified, then there will be three calls. With categorize wrapped in `Ember.run.once` , it will be only called once at the end of the chain.