# Ember.js - Managing Asynchronous Events & Callbacks

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm not using Ember Data, and have an ajax call in my Model to pull data from a remote source. After I've successfully received the data from the API, I want to sort/filter it based on category. My plan is that once I get the data from the Model, I can manage the filtered state of the data through the controller.

My problem is that because fetching the data in the Model is asynchronous, i can't exactly call a method in my controller to filter/sort the data to be displayed in the template.

The relevant pieces of my code, below and in [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rushi/q9dDJ). In my template iterating over `issue_list` I can easily display the information. However, I would like to iterate over the `categorized_issues` Array ... and I dont know when `issue_list` array *really* gets set so I can call the `categorize` method of the IssuesController.

```js
// Default Route for /issues
App.IssuesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function() {
        var issues = App.Issue.all(25);
        this.controllerFor('issues').processIssues(issues);
    }
});

// Model
App.Issue = Ember.Object.extend({});
App.Issue.reopenClass({
    // Fetch all issues from the ajax endpoint. 
    // Won't work on the JS fiddle
    all: function() {                
        var issues = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/issues.json",
            dataType: 'json',
        }).then(function(response) {
            response.issues.forEach(function(issue) {           
                issues.addObject(App.Issue.create(issue));
            }, this);
        });

        return issues;
    },
});

// Controller
App.IssuesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    issue_list: [],
    categorized_issues : {"open":[], "closed": []},

    processIssues: function(issues) {
        this.set('issue_list', issues);
        return issues;
    },

    categorize: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.issue_list.forEach(function(i) {
            // Based on the issue open or closed status
            if (i.status == "open") {
                self.categorized_issues["open"].addObject(i);
            } else {
                self.categorized_issues["closed"].addObject(i);
            }
        });
    },
});
```

So my plan is:

1. Fetch Data from Model
2. Re-categorize the data based on it's status (open or closed) in the controller.
3. Display this new data in the template.

I can seem to achieve this. Any ideas on how to go about it ?

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.2
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy solution would be to **declare `categorize()` as an observer**:

```
App.IssuesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    issue_list: [],
    categorized_issues : {"open":[], "closed": []},

    processIssues: function(issues) {
        this.set('issue_list', issues);
        return issues;
    },

    categorize: function() {
        var self = this;
        // clear the arrays to avoid redundant objects in the arrays
        self.get("categorized_issues.open").clear();
        self.get("categorized_issues.closed").clear();

        this.issue_list.forEach(function(i) {
            // Based on the issue open or closed status
            if (i.status == "open") {
                self.get("categorized_issues.open").addObject(i);
            } else {
                self.get("categorized_issues.closed").addObject(i);
            }
        });
    }.observes("issue_list.@each"),
});
```

This would mean that the observer would get triggered on each change of the array. This would be likely no performance problem in most cases. To ensure that `categorize` is just run once, **it would be even better, if you use `Ember.run.once`:**

```
App.IssuesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    issue_list: [],
    categorized_issues : {"open":[], "closed": []},

    processIssues: function(issues) {
        this.set('issue_list', issues);
        return issues;
    },
    issueListObserver : function(){
        Ember.run.once(this, this.categorize);
    }.observes('issue_list.@each'),

    categorize: function() {
        var self = this;
        // clear the arrays to avoid redundant objects in the arrays
        self.get("categorized_issues.open").clear();
        self.get("categorized_issues.closed").clear();

        this.issue_list.forEach(function(i) {
            // Based on the issue open or closed status
            if (i.status == "open") {
                self.get("categorized_issues.open").addObject(i);
            } else {
                self.get("categorized_issues.closed").addObject(i);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I completely missed the fact that I could observe on @each too. This was perfect, thank you very much!