# Ember.js REST Ajax Success and Error

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-data

I'd like to know what the `success` and `error` do in the Ember.js RESTAdapter's [ajax function](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/761412849a56ad086c44659faafa547d8f6c03a8/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L341-L347).

```
hash.success = function(json) {
  Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
};

hash.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
};
```

I know `hash` is the [data sent through AJAX](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/761412849a56ad086c44659faafa547d8f6c03a8/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L349), but what role do `success` and `error` play?  I assume they'd be run based on a successful or erroneous AJAX response, right? They're set before the AJAX is called, as callbacks? How do they work?

Comment: If my answer didn't satisfy your question it would be nice to know what's unclear so I can improve it further.

Comment: Hi intuitivepixel, I'm not skilled enough yet to fully comprehend the answer. I need to read up on the jQuery docs to avoid asking trivial questions. Thanks for the follow-up! I guess I can always comment on it if I have further questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but what role do success and error play? I assume they'd be run based on a successful or erroneous AJAX response, right?

Right, since ember uses jQuery under the hood the functions mentioned are just plain jQuery methods.

> They're set before the AJAX is called, as callbacks? How do they work?

As for the functions itself, see this info taken from the [jQuery official docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

- **error** callback option is invoked, if the request fails. It receives the jqXHR, a string indicating the error type, and an exception object if applicable. Some built-in errors will provide a string as the exception object: "abort", "timeout", "No Transport".
- **success** callback option is invoked, if the request succeeds. It receives the returned data, a string containing the success code, and the jqXHR object.

I should also mention that the `success` callback is in recently jQuery version being replaced with `done` and is marked as deprecated as noted here:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

But don't worry, because I guess until jQuery removes this methods completely the ember team has surely catched up with the new callback versions.

And finally if you where wondering what the call to `Ember.run` does you can have a look [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html). But basically it ensures that the passed target and method are run inside of a RunLoop, ensuring also any deferred actions like bindings and views updates, this are flushed at the end. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597869/what-is-ember-runloop-and-how-does-it-work) on the `Runloop` is also very informative.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @MikeGrassotti :) I already thought of proposing a PR to update to `done` and `fail`, but I'm somewhat concerned to introduce breaking changes by doing this...