# EmberJS Bindings Not Synchronizing?

Tags: ember.js

I'm upgrading my codebase from EmberJS-1.0-rc1 to EmberJS-1.0.

Many of my bindings don't seem to consistently synchronize anymore. The semantics must have changed, but I can't find out how, or what I should be doing instead!

```
var Widg = Ember.Object.extend({
    init: function () {
        this._super();

        console.log("aliasToValue is: ", this.get('aliasToValue'));
        if (this.get('aliasToValue') != this.get('value')) {
            throw "This exception doesn't get hit...";
        }

        console.log("Setting value to 'hello world'");
        this.set('value', "hello world");

        // I would expect:
        // this.get('value') == this.get('aliasToValue')
        // but that doesn't seem to work anymore....

        console.log("After settting, aliasToValue is: ", this.get('aliasToValue'));
        if (this.get('aliasToValue') != this.get('value')) {
            throw "Ugh, after setting, they don't match";
        }
    },
    value: "initial value",
    aliasToValueBinding: "value"
});

Widg.create(); // EXCEPTION: "Ugh, after setting, they don't match"
```

Comment: JSFiddle demonstrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/kxhUw/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember.bind does not stay in sync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121850/ember-bind-does-not-stay-in-sync)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a `propertyABinding: propertyB`, basically ember create an observer for `propertyA` and `propertyB` that schedule the syncronization (set the value of `propertyA` to `propertyB` and vice-versa) in the `sync` queue. Because that syncronization is scheduled, it will be executed just in the end of the runloop. So, the `aliasToValue` don't change:

```
this.set('value', "hello world");
this.get('value'); // return "hello world"
this.get('aliasToValue'); // return "initial value"
```

You can make the sync queue be flushed programatically calling `Ember.run.sync()`. So this will work:

```
this.set('value', "hello world");
this.get('value'); // return "hello world"
Ember.run.sync();   // don't wait for the end of runloop, and make the sync here
this.get('aliasToValue'); // return "hello world"
```

But to this work in your sample, you need to make some changes. In your case you are setting the properties in the `init` function. But in the init function, the observes isn't fired. So, no sync will be scheduled. You can use the `on('init')` to perform changes in the object when it is initialized:

```
...
didInit: function() {
   // now the observes will trigger when a property change
}.on('init')
...
```

Your code updated will be the following:

```
//the application
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.MyObject = Ember.Object.extend({
    didInit: function () {

        console.log("aliasToValue is: ", this.get('aliasToValue'));
        if (this.get('aliasToValue') != this.get('value')) {
            alert( "This exception doesn't get hit..." );
        }

        console.log("Setting value to 'hello world'");
        this.set('value', "hello world");

        // I would expect:
        // this.get('value') == this.get('aliasToValue')
        // but that doesn't seem to work anymore....

        console.log("After settting, aliasToValue is: ", this.get('aliasToValue'));
        Ember.run.sync();
        if (this.get('aliasToValue') != this.get('value')) {
            alert( "Ugh, after setting, they don't match" );
        }
    }.on('init'),
    value: "initial value",
    aliasToValueBinding: "value"
});

App.MyObject.create(); // EXCEPTION: "Ugh, after setting, they don't match"
```

And the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/Bk7L9/

Of course the `Ember.run.sync()` is just to be used in rare cases, removing it will make your templates and properties be updated, but when the runloop finish. I used it to you see the bound property update immediately.

For further information about the runloop see this answer [What is Ember RunLoop and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597869/what-is-ember-runloop-and-how-does-it-work)