# How to do loading indicator during rendering template in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Some parts of my ember.js application have to refresh and it takes several secends (for instance sorting elements in the loop). I would like to display loading image in the time of running through handlebars loop `#each`. How to do it?

```
{{#each}}
    {{! display some big data}}
{{/each}}
```

I don't want to do any ajax request indicator, only during loop, and I have to display all the data at one time.

Comment: You should use the loading route. Read the route guide for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Weird request but here you go...

In case you want to show the results that are fetched via the server.

```
{{#if bigData.isFulFilled}}
  {{#each object in bigData}}
    <! display some big data>
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  <! display some loading helper here>
{{/if}}
```

In other case , that your bottleneck is the processing speed ,maybe pass the array you want to show [in a `Ember.run` block](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html) in the controller   ,ensuring your array will be flushed only at the end of the loop.

```
App.BigDataController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  bigData: (function() {
    Ember.run(function() {
     <do your stuff here>
    });


  }).property()

});
```

After that do something like the above:

```
{{#if bigData}}
  {{#each object in bigData}}
    <! display some big data>
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  <! display some loading helper here>
{{/if}}
```

There's a [cool example here](https://machty.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-run-loop-visual/index.html) showing the Ember.run and [explained at this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597869/what-is-ember-runloop-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: It is not going to work. Handlebars #each is going to iterate approximetly 2 seconds. I won't have loading image during it in this case.

Comment: You are right, my mistake that I thought your problem was fetching records remotely. I've updated my answer